# What the java statement or function to format currency in Nigeria Naira currency

Tags: java, numbers, currency, sign

I want to know how to format currency in Nigeria naira format.
e.g.
If I calculate mortgage payment and the value is **150,000.00**. How can I format it to display **#150,000.00**

Comment: Did you have a look at `DecimalFormat` or `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale)`?

Comment: Thank you @Thomas. I try using NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale); but I received error message that the symbol Locale can not be found.

Comment: What exact error message do you get and what exact code did you use? Note that `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale)` was meant to point you to the correct method and not already compilable code - you need to select or build the correct `Locale` instance and pass it. Also note that not all locales are be supported out-of-the box so you _might_ actually have to build your own instance of `DecimalFormat` by providing a pattern (read the Javadoc on that class for what the pattern supports) and even `DecimalFormatSymbols` for the Nigerian locale.

Answer (score 2):

Please post detailed error msg to help you better.

I think the problem you have is related to importing classes.
when you use different classes you should import them, usually the IDE do that automatically.
here I imported

import java.text.NumberFormat;

import java.util.Locale;

As for the solution you should define locale first, language/ country.

the language use ISO 639 codes ,the country use ISO 3166 codes
you can get those codes from wikipedia, etc...

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Format{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    

           int value = 15000000;
            
            Locale nigeria = new Locale("en", "NG");
            
            NumberFormat numFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(nigeria);

            System.out.println(numFormat.format(value));
        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a string of `"150,000.00"`, so you can just prepend your `#`, as of

```
String formatted = "#" + yourstring;
```